# when I click on android flutter deep link URL in messaging, it open my app activity in same messaging app instead of new app tab

Tags: android, flutter, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I want to open my app activity separate tab instead of same URL host messaging app

I am getting open my deep link URL in same host app but instead I want to open my app separately in new TAB.
I used custom deep link method no third party. what I need to change in the android.xml file.

Comment: Does your android activity tagged as  "singleTask" (eg: <activity  android:name=".MainActivity"  android:launchMode="singleTask")

Comment: thanks @VincentDR sir,  this launchMode working as expected but with this launch mode problem is  android can't open new app page to different deep link if the previous app page is open in background. is it default behavior of android for this launch mode.

Answer (score 0):

in MainActivity in xml file
you can change android:launchMode to "singleInstance" like
android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 0):

i know it's late but it'll help someone else.

go to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file (path: android/app/src/main)
and look for activity tag of `.MainActivity` in application tag,
now change the value of launch mode to "singleTask"

`android:launchMode="singleTop"` => `android:launchMode="singleTask"`